# schema matching

Tags: xml, xsd

i am interested in schema matching, i have build two xml schemas,and know i want to compare and nmatch these schemas, there is many tools that can perform matching process,
but i need a tool that is a vailable on the internet and free.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

ISX Wand Fujitsu and touchstone might help you ,but you need to purchase them.

There is addon on mozilla which will help you a lot..

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xml-developer-toolbar/